# ctypes structure arrays in python

Tags: python, c++, pointers, ctypes

I'm trying to have a pointer created to nested structure array. But to c++ only first structure elements are passed...

C++ code:

```
typedef structure
{
int One;
int Two;
}nestedStru; 

typedef structure
{
int First;
nestedStru* Poniter; //Pointer to nested structure array
}mainStru;
```

Equivalent python code:

```
class nestedStru(Structure)
    _fields_ = [("One",c_uint8),          
        ("Two",c_uint8)]

class mainStru(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("First",c_uint8),
                ("PointerToNested",POINTER(nestedStru))]
```

I tried creating an object of main class and cast pointer to array objects..

```
object = mainStru()
object.Second = cast((nestedStru * 2)(), POINTER(nestedStru))
```

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your question? does it throw an error?

Comment: object.Second[0].One = 8
object.Second[0].Two = 1
object.Second[1].One = 8
object.Second[1].Two = 1

If I pass this object through a function to C++ code using byref , second structure elements are not passed

No error is thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `c_uint8`, which is 8-bit, while your structure uses `int`, in ctypes `c_int`, usually 32-bit.

Your structures should be:

```
class nestedStru(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
      ("One", c_int),          
      ("Two", c_int)
    ]

class mainStru(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
      ("First", c_int),
      ("Poniter", POINTER(nestedStru))
    ]
```

This is a test library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  int One;
  int Two;
} nestedStru; 

typedef struct
{
  int First;
  nestedStru* Poniter; // Pointer to nested structure array
} mainStru;

void
func(const mainStru *obj, size_t s)
{
  size_t i;

  for( i = 0 ; i < s ; i++ )
  {
    printf("%d, %d\n", obj->Poniter[i].One, obj->Poniter[i].Two);
  }
}
```

Python client:

```
#!python
from ctypes import *

class nestedStru(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
      ("One", c_int),          
      ("Two", c_int)
    ]

class mainStru(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
      ("First", c_int),
      ("Poniter", POINTER(nestedStru))
    ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = mainStru()
    obj.First = 0
    obj.Poniter = (nestedStru * 3)((1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33))

    func = CDLL('./lib.dll').func
    func.argtypes = [POINTER(mainStru), c_size_t]
    func.restype = None

    func(obj, 3)
```

now it works fine:

```
> gcc -Wall lib.c -o lib.dll -shared
> python file.py
1, 11
2, 22
3, 33
>
```